# PHP Exec Ping Destination host unreachable

Tags: php, exec, ping, router

I am pinging a couple computers (192.168.200.1 and 192.168.200.2) on my corporate lan that are behind a router (192.168.200.254).

```
function pingAddress($TEST) {
$pingresult = exec("ping -n 1 $TEST", $output, $result);
    if ($result == 0) {
        echo "Ping successful!";
        } else {
        echo "Ping unsuccessful!";
        }

    }
pingAddress("192.168.220.1");
pingAddress("192.168.220.2");
```

My issue is that is one of these computer is not powered on ( .1 ) and still I get a ping response.

```
Pinging 192.168.200.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.200.254: Destination host unreachable.
Ping statistics for 192.168.200.1:
Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

var_dump($output) on 192.168.220.1 ping attempt is showing as:

```
array(6) { 
[0]=> string(0) "" 
[1]=> string(44) "Pinging 192.168.200.1 with 32 bytes of data:" 
[2]=> string(57) "Reply from 192.168.200.254: Destination host unreachable." 
[3]=> string(0) "" 
[4]=> string(34) "Ping statistics for 192.168.200.1:" 
[5]=> string(56) " Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss)," 
}
```

So I am instead am trying to search the $output array that is created for the false positive "Destination host unreachable" message but not having luck with this route.

```
function pingAddress($TEST) {
$findme ="Destination host unreachable";

    $pingresult = exec("ping -n 1 $TEST  && exit", $output, $result);
        //echo $result. "<br/>";
        if (($result == 0) AND (in_array($findme, $output))){
            echo "Ping unsuccessful! <br/>";
        }
        elseif (($result == 0) AND (!in_array($findme, $output))){
            echo "Ping successful! <br/>";
        }
        elseif ($result == 1){
            echo "Ping unsuccessful! <br/>";
        }    
}
pingAddress("192.168.220.1");
pingAddress("192.168.220.2");
```

Still shows as successful. I am probably doing something wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: in_array won't work because it needs to match the entire value of the element. Instead, I would probably do something goofy like join the array into a single string and preg_match for the string you're looking for. Or, if you think it's a safe assumption, just preg_match on the 3rd element of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is [preg_grep](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php). Give this a try:

```
function pingAddress($TEST) {
    $pingresult = exec("ping -n 1 $TEST  && exit", $output, $result);
    //echo $result. "<br/>";

    if (($result == 0)){
        if(count(preg_grep('/Destination host unreachable/i', $output)) == 0){
            echo "Ping successful! <br/>";
        else
            echo "Ping unsuccessful! <br/>";
    }
    elseif ($result == 1){
        echo "Ping unsuccessful! <br/>";
    }
```

}

Comment: Worked great, found this as well.

Answer (score 0):

in_array will expect the whole string i.e. "Reply from 192.168.200.254: Destination host unreachable." . You can use `strstr` [php manual strstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) php function or regular expression check instead. And since it's in the array - like someone suggested .. join the string of the array and try to find the text.